# Gson как распарсить во внутреннем объекте nullable-поле?

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, null

Я знаю что если указать `serializeNulls()` тогда объект раскладывается с null-полями.
У меня возникла сложность с вложенным классом, который должен парсится с null-полями, но это не должно относится к внешнему классу, который парсится обязательно без null-полей (хотя они могут в нем присутствовать).
null-поля во внешнем классе нельзя использовать из-за ограничений backend. Поэтому нельзя использовать `serializeNulls()` на главном `Gson`
**Пример для наглядности:**

```
основной пример объекта
{
    "name": "Anna",
    "age": 40,
    "pet" : {
        "name" : "snowball",
        "type" : 2
    }
}
```

```
{
    "name" : "Bob"
    "age" : 30,
    "pet" : {
        "name" : "smoky",
        "type" : null    //Корректный вариант. Но это поле не могу распарсить
    }
}
```

```
{
    "name" : "Carol",
    "age" : null, //ошибка. Во внешнем объекте не должно быть null
    "pet" : {
        "name" : "twiky",
        "type" : null //как распарсить это, не затрагивая внешний объект
    }
}
```

когда я указываю внутренний парсер через `registerTypeAdapter` - он возвращает корретный `json` (пример2 `{"name":"smoky","type":null}`), но после прохода через внешний `Gson` - null-значение стирается (пример2 `{"name":"Bob","age":30,"pet":{"name":"smoky"}}`)

**Пример с кодом:**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pet pet1 = new Pet("snowball", 2);
        Person anna = new Person("Anna", 40, pet1);

        Pet pet2 = new Pet(null, 1);
        Person bob = new Person("Bob", 30, pet2);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(Pet.class, new PetParser())
                .create();

        System.out.println(gson.toJson(anna) + "\n");//{"name":"Anna","age":40,"pet":{"name":"snowball","type":2}}
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(bob) + "\n");//{"name":"Bob","age":30,"pet":{"type":1}} <- null-поле исчезло
    }

    public static class PetParser implements JsonSerializer<Pet> {
        @Override
        public JsonElement serialize(Pet pet, Type type, JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext) {
            Gson childGson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
            System.out.printf("pet:" + childGson.toJsonTree(pet) + "\n");
            return childGson.toJsonTree(pet);
            //anna pet:{"name":"snowball","type":2}
            //bob pet:{"name":null,"type":1} <- null-поле есть
        }
    }
```

Comment: А в чем проблема? Главный и дочерний объект, никак не связаны, во всех случаях pet не равен null

Comment: @danilshik, у меня во внешнем объекте стирается null-поле

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверное, никак. Такой случай, как у вас, разработчики `Gson` не предусмотрели.
Загляните в исходники метода

```
public void toJson(Object src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonWriter writer)
```

там `setSerializeNulls` выставляется для `JsonWriter`, все элементы туда пишутся одинаково, кастомный сериализатор на этом ничего не меняет.

Верным решением будет договориться с бэкендом, это ненормально тут принимать `null`, а тут нет.

**ДОПОЛНЕНО**
Как вот тут пишут
https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#null-object-support
`PetParser` просто добавляет `JsonNull` элемент при сериализации, но потом в `toJson()` уровнем выше это игнорируется и все `null` опускаются.

Т.е. при текущей реализации этой фичи в Gson -- никак.

Comment: Можете подсказать парсер, в котором реализована эта идея?

Comment: Попробуйте Jackson, у него можно добавить свой NullSerializer, может что получится для вашего случая. https://www.thesunflowerlab.com/blog/jsonnullserializer-write-custom-serializer/

Comment: Спасибо за прояснение ситуации